# React component "sometimes" doesn't find a prop

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

This is a very strange issue and wanted to see if anyone else has experienced it.

Sometimes, my react component doesn't find the property of a prop. I say sometimes because sometimes the page renders perfectly fine. Other times, it doesn't find the prop and if I refresh it twice or so, it then starts to work.

I thought the issue could be with the bundled and minified JS file so I switched to the file that WebPack Dev server serves on the fly and I have the same issue.

It's hard to see what's causing the issue because it's intermittent. Why would it fail in one case then once page is refreshed a few times, it starts to work?

I don't think this is important but I'm accessing a property of an object as below:

```
<MyComponent name={this.props.account.accountHolder.firstName} />
```

If I debug it when I get the error, I see that firstName is `undefined`. Refresh the page a few times and everything works fine.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: How is the data being populated? Is it from api calls? Static files?

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Is the data loaded via Ajax, but your component doesn't wait for the data to arrive before it renders?

Comment: The object gets populated after an API call and goes into my Redux store.

Comment: Whats going to be most helpful is seeing the component that subscribes to the account prop and also the reducer that handles loading the api payload into the redux store.

Comment: @sam please show a [mcve], because in making that, you may already figure out what's wrong all on your own, but if you don't, you have much better code to show people that they can run and see the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be battling with race conditions.

Case 1 (everything works out):

1. Your app is loaded
2. Your ajax request is sent
3. Your ajax request is returned and data is inserted into redux
4. Your apps render method is called
5. Profit

Case 2:

1. Your app is loaded
2. Your ajax request is sent
3. Your apps render method is called
4. Kaput!
5. Your ajax request is returned and data is inserted into redux

So the solution depends somewhat on the state of your reducer and what is your expected behavior, but I would suggest, on your component do some verification that data actually exists, if it doesn't display something else (null, loading spinner, error message, w/e) until the correct prop is actually populated and you can display the child component.